# Lost in SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2

I try to generate title in all levels of the officers but I get only the more detailed title. How can i correct the statement?

Currently, I get the more detailed title like 99ABC but i want to get the all combinations.

```
99---
99--C
99-B-
99A--
99-BC
99A-C
99AB-
99ABC


  select distinct TITLE 
   from (SELECT         
        (case when OFF3.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || 
        coalesce( OFF2.INDICATOR, '-') || coalesce( OFF3.INDICATOR, '-') 
        else case when OFF2.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || coalesce( OFF2.INDICATOR, '-') || '-' 
        else case when OFF1.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || '--' 
        else DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || '---' end end end ) as TITLE 

        FROM DEPARTMENT DEP, 
        TEAM TEA 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFICER OFF1 ON OFF1.OFFICER1_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFICER OFF2 ON OFF2.OFFICER2_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFICER OFF3 ON OFF3.OFFICER3_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 

        WHERE TEA.TEAM_DEPA_ID = DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID 
            AND TEA.TEAM_MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL 
            AND coalesce( TEA.TEAM_MANAGER_ID, OFF1.TEAM_OFFICER_ID, OFF2.TEAM_OFFICER_ID, OFF3.TEAM_OFFICER_ID ) is not null ) myselect
```

P.S. `||` is used for concetenate operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED, to remove CTE) Try:

```
select distinct TITLE from 
(SELECT case title_case
             when 0 then TITLE0
             when 1 then TITLE1
             when 2 then TITLE2
             when 3 then TITLE3
        end as TITLE
 FROM
    (SELECT 0 title_case FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
     SELECT 1 title_case FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 title_case FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 title_case FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) tc
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT case when OFF3.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                      then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || coalesce( OFF2.INDICATOR, '-') || coalesce( OFF3.INDICATOR, '-') 
            end as TITLE3,
            case when OFF2.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                      then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || coalesce( OFF2.INDICATOR, '-') || '-' 
            end as TITLE2,
            case when OFF1.OFFICER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                      then DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || coalesce( OFF1.INDICATOR, '-') || '--' 
            end as TITLE1,
            DEP.INDICATOR || TEA.INDICATOR || '---' as TITLE0
     FROM DEPARTMENT DEP
     JOIN TEAM TEA ON TEA.TEAM_DEPA_ID = DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID 
     LEFT JOIN OFFICER OFF1 ON OFF1.OFFICER1_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 
     LEFT JOIN OFFICER OFF2 ON OFF2.OFFICER2_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 
     LEFT JOIN OFFICER OFF3 ON OFF3.OFFICER3_TEAM_ID = TEA.TEAM_ID 
     WHERE TEA.TEAM_MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL 
    ) mytitles
) myselect
```

Comment: @mark-banister . Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to do it without `with` operator?

Comment: @Kayser: Yes, but the answer would be less easy to understand. `WITH` should be a standard part of DB2 SQL - why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @mark-banister i will put this query in another query like `select * from (myselect) where...` In from it is not allowed..

Comment: @Kayser: I have edited the query to replace the CTE with equivalent functionality.